# MySQL Sum not correct and join

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm building a holiday system and one of the features is being able to buy extra holiday which you can do at several points of the year, so I'm wanting to see the total number of days holiday, how much has been booked and how much has been bought by each user.

I'm doing a query

```
SELECT  hr_user.name AS username, 
        hr_user.user_id,
        SUM(working_days) AS daysbooked, 
        sum(hr_buyback.days) AS daysbought 
FROM hr_leave 
inner join hr_user on hr_user.user_id = hr_leave.user_id
left outer join hr_buyback on hr_buyback.user_id = hr_user.user_id
where    active = 'y' 
     and hr_leave.start_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' 
     and (hr_leave.status = 'approved' OR hr_leave.status = 'pending')
GROUP BY hr_user.name, hr_user.user_id
```

Now this is bringing back results in the daysbought column waaaay higher than what I was expecting, which is odd because when I get rid of the sum and just have hr_buyback.days it shows all the individual values I'd expect (except I'd much rather they were summed)

Secondly, in MySQL can you do what you can in MSSQL which is

```
left outer join hr_buyback on (select hr_buyback.user_id where buy_sell = 'buy') = hr_leave.user_id
```

?

Relevant table definitions (I assume this is what you mean?):

hr_buyback

```
buyback_id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
user_id     int(11) NO          
days        int(11) NO          
buy_sell    varchar(10) NO          
status      varchar(10) NO      pending 
year        int(11) NO
```

hr_user

```
user_id     int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
name        varchar(40) NO          
email       varchar(40) NO  UNI     
level       int(5)  YES         
manager_id  int(11) NO          
team_id     int(11) YES         
active      varchar(2)  NO      y   
holidays_day    int(11) NO          
start_date  timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
password    varchar(60) NO          
division_id int(11) YES         
day_change  int(5)  NO      0   
priv_hours  varchar(2)  NO      n   
po_level    int(2)  YES     0   
po_signoff  int(10) YES
```

hr_leave

```
leave_id    int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
user_id     int(11) NO          
start_date  date    NO          
end_date    date    NO          
day_type    varchar(10) NO          
status      varchar(20) NO      pending 
working_days    varchar(5)  NO          
leave_type  int(11) NO          
cancel      int(11) NO      0   
date        timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: can you include your table definitions?

Comment: The second code snippet is missing a `FROM` clause.  I'd write it in a different format, but yes - MySQL supports inline views/derived tables.

Comment: When you get a large number of records back when you were expecting a small number it usually indicates a cartesian join and suggests you've not joined your tables properly.

Comment: @DaveRlz I'm getting the right number of records back but for some reason the sum() is adding something I can't quite work out.  I'm pretty sure the joins are right because if I'm selecting the individual records without the sum() it's showing the correct figures?

Comment: I also see that `working_days` is a `VARCHAR` instead of and `INT` - you might want change the datatype or use `SUM(CONVERT(working_days, UNSIGNED))` to make sure it is being handled correctly.

Comment: @sam.clements - your `GROUP BY` can mask an incorrect join that will result in higher `SUM` values than you expected.

Comment: Grouping by just the `hr_user.user_id` should be sufficient, and necessary in case any of the `hr_user.name` values are the same for different users.

Comment: @doublesharp thanks for the spot on the varchar - not entirely sure why it was built that way but I don't want to mess with it too much so I'll convert to check the calculation!

Comment: @doublesharp does MySQL not need all items in the select list to be in a group or aggregate function then like MSSQL?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with MSSQL, but MySQL does not have that requirement. After re-reading it probably won't affect your output, but also isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you will get one copy of each row from `hr_buyback` for each matching row in `hr_leave`.

I assume that it is possible to have more than one `hr_buyback` row per user, and that it is possible to have a `hr_buyback` row without a `hr_leave` row. If so, you'll probably want something like this:

```
SELECT  hr_user.name AS username, 
    hr_user.user_id,
    SUM(working_days) AS daysbooked, 
        (SELECT SUM(days) 
        FROM hr_buyback 
        WHERE hr_buyback.user_id = hr_user.user_id) AS daysbought 
FROM  hr_user  
left join hr_leave on hr_user.user_id = hr_leave.user_id
where    active = 'y' 
 and hr_leave.start_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' 
 and (hr_leave.status = 'approved' OR hr_leave.status = 'pending')
GROUP BY hr_user.name, hr_user.user_id
```